# Restarting for loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

In the last line of the code below, I want to go back to the top of the for loop, but still have code below in case the answer isn't 'no'.

```
  for i in range(13):
    choice = input('Would you like a '+comp_choice[i]+'? Yes or no: ')
    if choice == 'yes':
      items+=comp_choice[i]
      stock[i]-=1
    elif choice == 'no':
```

Comment: You mean `continue`?

Comment: elif choice == 'no': pass ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `continue`. 
It exists is procedural languages.
The `continue` keyword is used to stop the current iteration of a loop, no code will be executed if you call it.

Unlike the `break` keyword, which will interrupt the loop, `continue` will proceed with the next iteration.

If I understood you question right, this is exactly what you need.